# CallKit Audio session starts when navigating to the application only

Tags: ios, voip, avaudiosession, callkit

I'm working on a voip app now and want to support holding.
But when a second call comes and I hold my current call. Switching to my first call I hear no sound at all.
The way to hear it is to navigate from callKit native screen to my app and hence I can hear the voice.

```
func configureAudioSession() {

    _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .videoChat, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
    _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
    _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)
}

func startAudio() {
    print("Starting audio")

    do {
        _ = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
    }
}

  func stopAudio() {
    print("Stopping audio")

    do {
        _ = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For supporting holding, you dont have to start/stop audio session, instead you can use `CXSetHeldCallAction` provided by Callkit itself. Here, is the code for hold that i use.

```
let callKitCallController = CXCallController()

func performHoldAction(isOnHold:Bool, uuid:UUID) {
    let holdCallAction = CXSetHeldCallAction(call: uuid, onHold: isOnHold)
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: holdCallAction)
    callKitCallController.request(transaction) { error in
        if let error = error {
            CPrint("holdCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription).")
            return
        }
        CPrint("holdCallAction transaction request successful")
    }
}
```

Once system puts the call on hold(by above method OR due to other incoming call accepting or any other reason), then in `CXProviderDelegate`, the method `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction)` gives you the callback for the detail.

Here, system/callkit itself interacts with audio, you dont have to explicitly start or stop audio for holding.

Note: Make sure that you given `supportsHolding` to `true` for the `CXCallUpdate` that you gave for new call.

Comment: Shall I call this inside `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) ` delegate method.?

Comment: No... you need to call `performHoldAction` method when you want to hold the call.(may be your button action or something else).  `provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction)` this method will get called by system and provided to you when hold successfully happens

Comment: I call it inside `func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {` But when swapping calls, same problem occurs (no sound till I navigate to the app).

Comment: I mean when shall I call this method?